# How to fix error with new Firestore version?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Hey I recently updated my cloud_firestore dependency from version 0.12.9+4 to 2.2.1. Now I have to make some changes in my code. I already read how to migrate the code for version 2.0.0 and changed parts of the code. But I dont get how to change it in this part:

```
 //imbiss list from snapshot
  List<Imbiss> _imbissListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
      return Imbiss(
        name: doc.data["name"],
        kind: doc.data["kind"],
        location: doc.data["location"],
        rating: doc.data["rating"],
        ratingFood: doc.data["ratingFood"],
        ratingLocation: doc.data["ratingLocation"],
        ratingPLV: doc.data["ratingPLV"],
        ratingService: doc.data["ratingService"],
        date: doc.data["date"],
        user: doc.data["user"],
      );
    }).toList();
  }
```

The code worked perfectly fine before and now I'm getting an error for the brackets after *doc.data*. Android Studio tells me: *The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object Function().* Do you have any clue what I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  List<Imbiss> _imbissListFromSnapshot(AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
      Map<String, dynamic> newDoc = doc.data();
      return Imbiss(
        name: newDoc["name"],
        kind: newDoc["kind"],
        location: newDoc["location"],
        rating: newDoc["rating"],
        ratingFood: newDoc["ratingFood"],
        ratingLocation: newDoc["ratingLocation"],
        ratingPLV: newDoc["ratingPLV"],
        ratingService: newDoc["ratingService"],
        date: newDoc["date"],
        user: newDoc["user"],
      );
    }).toList();
  }
```

Comment: This one worked for me, but I used _QuerySnapshot_ instead of _AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>_. And I also had to pass a default value as in sungkd123's answer

Answer (score 0):

Use this for QuerySnapshot, '' after ?? is the default value passed, please change the default value according to the datatype

```
 //imbiss list from snapshot
  List<Imbiss> _imbissListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
      return Imbiss(
        name: doc.get("name") ?? '' ,
        kind: doc.get("kind") ?? '',
        location: doc.get("location") ?? '',
        rating: doc.get("rating") ?? '',
        ratingFood: doc.get("ratingFood") ?? '' ,
        ratingLocation: doc.get("ratingLocation") ?? '' ,
        ratingPLV: doc.get("ratingPLV")  ?? '' ,
        ratingService: doc.get("ratingService") ?? '' ,
        date: doc.get("date") ?? '' ,
        user: doc.get("user") ?? '',
      );
    }).toList();
  }
```

And this for DocumentSnapshot

```
  //imbiss list from snapshot
      List<Imbiss> _imbissListFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
        return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
          return Imbiss(
            name: snapshot.get("name")  ,
            kind: snapshot.get("kind") ,
            location: snapshot.get("location") ,
            rating: snapshot.get("rating"),
            ratingFood: snapshot.get("ratingFood"),
            ratingLocation: snapshot.get("ratingLocation") ,
            ratingPLV: snapshot.get("ratingPLV")  ,
            ratingService: snapshot.get("ratingService") ,
            date: snapshot.get("date"),
            user: snapshot.get("user"),
          );
        }).toList();
      }
```